# grabbing x,y coordinates of a mouse click/release from Tkinter GUI to do some calculations (not only to print out)

Tags: python, tkinter, click, bind

I try to grab the coordinates of the mouse clicked/released points to do other calculations with them, using "bind" on a Tkinter GUI. I know that the purpose of binding is not for the program to wait for a mouse click where exactly they're defined. But, I need the coordinates (x,y) of the clicked/released points to do the further calculations, and the program already reaches to these calculations before letting me to click on the GUI. All the answers to similar questions out there mostly output x and y using "print" (which is the simplest solution). I couldn't find any way to be able to click, grab the coordinates, and then use them further in the code. Here's part of my code. Any thoughts?

```
class imageLabel(Tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        Tk.Label.__init__(self)
        self.label = Tk.Label(self,image=[], height=600,width=2000)
        self.pack()

    def select_ROI (self):
        self.bound = []
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_click)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_click)

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.bound.append(event.x)
        self.bound.append(event.y)
        if len(self.bound)==4:
            self.unbind('<ButtonPress-1>')
            self.unbind('<ButtonRelease-1>')
```

I have other functions in this class, and that's why I initialized it so. Now, if I use it in the main program as:

```
...
imageDisp   = imageLabel(UsrInp)
imageDisp.select_ROI()
print "boundaries: ", imageDisp.bound
alpha = (imageDisp.bound[0]+ imageDisp.bound[2])/2
...
```

I get this error (before I get a chance to click on GUI):

```
boundaries:  []
...
alpha = (imageDisp.bound[0]+ imageDisp.bound[2])/2
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That error usually means that `imageDisp` has a value that is different than what you are assuming it has. Have you done any debugging to see what is in that list before trying to use an index on it?

Comment: imageDisp.bound (that arises the error), is initialized with [ ] within the "select_ROI" function. It seems that its content is not being changed ("boundaries" that I printed out is "imageDisp.bound" ).  And, the reason is that its content should be the x and y of the clicked point, but I never get the chance to click on the GUI before the program reaches to this point (which is the problem that I seek help with).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your intent is for your program to pause, and wait for the user to click before continuing. That is, you want the flow to be this:

1. `imageDisp   = imageLabel(UsrInp)`
2. `imageDisp.select_ROI()`
3. (wait for the user to click)
4. `alpha = (imageDisp.bound[0]+ imageDisp.bound[2])/2`

That is not normally how GUIs work. Usually you set events and then respond to events, rather than explicitly waiting for a specific event.

However, what you want to do is possible. You just need to cause `select_ROI` to not return until the clicks happen. The simplest way is to have your program wait on a variable, then make sure that your event bindings causes that variable to be set.

First, create a flag in `imageLabel.__init__` that can be used later:

```
class imageLabel(Tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.var = Tk.BooleanVar()
        ...
```

Next, in `select_ROI`, wait for that variable to be set before returning:

```
def select_ROI (self):
    ...
    self.wait_variable(self.var)
    return
```

Finally, make sure that your bindings set this flag:

```
def on_click(self, event):
    ...
    if len(self.bound)==4:
        ...
        self.var.set(True)
```

That will cause `select_ROI` to wait for the user to click and release before returning.

Be aware that this can lead to a very confusing user experience if you don't give the user sufficient feedback on what they are supposed to do, and you don't take steps to prevent them from doing anything else before they do the clicks.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much. I was not aware of "wait_variable".